# Navigate to a fragment with navArgs using notification

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, notifications, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm new with working with notifications in my app so please bear with me.
I have a pending intent which will navigate to MainActivity when the user clicks on it. I want to change it so that it navigates to a fragment that has navigation arguments.

**My code for pending intent**

```
        val notifyIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            data = Uri.parse(uri)
        }
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
```

**Navigation action for my fragment**

```
       NavigationGraphMainDirections.actionGlobalManagePostFragment("data")
```

I don't know if I have to send the string of data with the notification and get it back with the pending intent.
What is the solution here?

Comment: Seems like you want a deep link. This docs may help: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link

Comment: That was what I needed. Thanks. @BMacedo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is to use an explicit deep link.

Create your pending intent as in:

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
.setDestination(R.id.android)
.setArguments(args)
.createPendingIntent()
```

Comment: how to trigger that intent ?

Comment: Add it to your Notification Builder:
`NotificationCompat.Builder(...).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)`

Comment: if I  need to set as setGraph a nested graph?
my destination is never called. How can I solve?

Comment: I am creating a pending intent with background push notification. But as is not running so  I am getting NPE in NavDeepLinkBuilder class for `android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()`

Comment: Yes, it's a working solution if an application is running & in the foreground.
It fails to navigate to the destination fragment when the app not running/ not in the background.
How we can achieve the same functionality when the app not running?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a pending Intent like this:

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.your_navigation_graph_id)
            .setDestination(R.id.id_that_fragment_you_want_to_open)
            .setArguments(arg_value_if_you_have)
            .createPendingIntent()
```

Then use pending intent like this:

```
 val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            . and ...
```